# Sequelize migrations resulting in different outcomes in different databases

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I have two similar databases: production and development.
i noticed that in one of the development tables a enum type column(status) is different than the one in production.

```
status: {
    defaultValue: "INACTIVE",
    allowNull: false,
    type: DataTypes.ENUM,
    values: ["INACTIVE", "EMAILED_PASS", "PASS_RESET"],
  }
```

status column in development table was missing `INACTIVE`
I tried to run the migrations in development branch but the migrations were up to date, even deleted all the tables in development database and ran the migrations from scratch. still the column doesn't change. but when i do the same with production database the column is correct.

I am new to sequelize and i might probably be missing something simple.